# Visual Studio Code: how to enable props autocompletion for TSX components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

Let's say I have a component Lalo which requries the props height and width.

```
interface I {
  width: string;
  height: string
}

const Lalo: React.FC<I> = (props) => {
   return <div>
            <div>props.height</div>
            <div>props.width</div>
          </div>
}
```

How do I setup Visual Studio Code so when it autocompletes "Lalo" it also adds placeholders for the required props?
Today, If I type `<La` it shows me the suggestion for Lalo and when I press enter it produces `<Lalo`. I want it to produce `<Lalo height="" width=""` and include all required props as specified in the typescript definition.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [React PropTypes Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OfHumanBondage.react-proptypes-intellisense) extension and while it provides an auto-complete functionality, It does not add required fields by default when you select the component.

Another way to show component props in the suggestion list is by using [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started.html). It's basically comments that you write above the declaration that defines the arguments and its types. [Check this article](https://dev.to/maxbvrn/react-props-auto-complete-in-vs-code-2ana) it explains how to use it in details.